# Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 532676549 (with execute statement in firebird 2.5)

Tags: firebird

I have a problem with execeute statement in a stored procedure and i cant figure it out, i try the text of the query in a variable, show it in a exception to see if was well, copy and execute it and worket, but inside the execute statement i get the same error "Unexpected end of command - line 1, column 532676549"

```
execute statement 'insert into rep_balancediario(id_rep_balancediario,id_plancuenta,id_saldocontable,nivel,codigoreducido,
        SALDOANTERIOR,CREDITO,DEBITO,SALDODIA, cuentacontable,imputable,id_moneda,contracuenta,saldocontabledes,ID_SUCURSALAGENCIA)
        values(gen_id(id_rep_balancediario,1),'||:v_id_PlanCuenta||','||:V_NROSALDOCONTABLE||','||:v_Nivel||',"'||:v_CodigoReducido||'",'||
        :V_SALDOANTERIORMN||','||:V_CREDITOMN||','||:V_DEBITOMN||','||:v_resultadosaldoactual||',"'||cast(:v_CuentaContable as VARCHAR(11))||'","S",'
        ||:v_nromoneda||',
        "'||cast(:v_contracuenta as VARCHAR (11))||'","'||cast(:V_DESSALDOCONTABLE as VARCHAR(255))||' >'||cast(:v_des_suc as varchar(100))||'",'
        ||:VE_IDSUCURSALAGENCIA||')'
       --:V_str_sql
       with AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;
```

does some one know what could by the problem?

Comment: First reading columns are more than values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unexpected end of command usually means that the parser reached the end of the statement while it was still expecting tokens, or reached a parser state where it should be complete but there are still tokens left. The fact you are concatenating values into the query is a red flag. Also the "column 532676549" could be an indication of problem, as that exceeds query length limits (64k in Firebird 2.5 and earlier), and also suggests you have literals that are larger than supported (32k).

[Execute statement supports parametrized queries](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt-wparams): use it. I'd suggest that you rewrite your query to a parametrized query and see if that works, as an example:

```
execute statement ('insert into aTable (column1, column2) values (?, ?)') (aVariable, 'literal');
```

or

```
execute statement ('insert into aTable (column1, column2) values (:var1, :var2)') (var1 := aVariable, var2 := 'literal');
```

I also see that your query contains double quotes where I'd expect single quotes, which suggests that you use the deprecated dialect 1, which brings yet another set of potential problems.